# Wildfly 10 session replication fails in domain mode

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-10, mod-cluster

I followed instructions which is given at https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Clustering+and+Domain+Setup+Walkthrough
I used mod_cluster 1.2.6 and wildfly 10. Slave node registers to master domain controller.

Load balancing is working as i seen but session replication is not working.

I realized artemismq configuration should be set up in domain.xml but it is not mentioned in documentation.

Is there something else to be configured.
If there is tutorial or sample configuration i will be really grateful.

Comment: Have you tried cluster deployment for JBoss EAP 7 in standalone mode using Apache HTTPD mod_cluster. I have similar question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43454068/load-balancing-cluster-not-working-with-apache-http-server-2-4-6-and-jboss-eap-7